# Where can I find this green nature iPad mini wallpaper used in Apple's advert?

Tags: ipad

Can somebody help me find this wallpaper in high resolution? (image taken from http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is available at PAPERS.co in both parallax and normal versions:

- http://papers.co/ma28-frog-boy-leaf-flower-nature/

[image]